# error googleplayservice update in googlemap view java android

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I use googlemap v2 in my app

on most device,googlemap show well

but in some device, show update button(for googleplayservice) in mapview

while in same device,other app that use googlemap have no problem(error update)

how solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an issue with your code. As the google map uses the play services of the device, so the app user's device must have play service version equal or higher than the one mentioned in your app.gradle dependencies. In the devices where the play service version is lower than the one specified in dependency, it gives an option to update play services first.

Comment: Thanks my friend.

Should i do change google_play_services_version in file integers.xml file to low version?

Comment: I think you do not need to do that, as it is best to have latest library dependency in the code. But if you don't want to force your app user to upgrade the play services you can think about lowering the google_play_services_ version.

Comment: Yes i know dont need to do that

I use last version googleplayservice but not affect on my problem

Answer (score 0):

I think need to use update googleplayservice.jar in my project but it is not solving